# User Authentication on iOS - How?

Tags: ios, authentication, passwords

I wonder if someone may be able to help me please?  I've been trying to find an article which can run me through username / password authentication within iOS with limited success.  I found a good article from http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1 and I thought this would answer my questions.  Unfortunately, I hit a snag after following the tutorial to the letter whereby I was just presented with a blank screen.  Whilst I've contacted Chris Lowe (the chap who done the tutorial) I haven't had a response back and I've hit a bit of a brick wall.

I wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction where I could learn how to do this and whether there were any code snippets which could be used etc etc?

Ideally I'm trying to get my application to prompt users for a username / email and password so that I can authenticate them using a web service connection from a company called parse.com.  Its all very very new to me and I'm struggling but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Sean

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/181292

Comment: Thanks Borrrden for your response.  Appreciate it may seem like I haven't put any effort in but I can assure you I've been reading up on this for days without much success.  Maybe its because I'm not using the right terminology or something? If you feel I should remove this question, please let me know and I'll go elsewhere.

Comment: The problem is that you need to ask a more specific question.  SO is not good at fielding "My code doesn't work in general" questions.  Be more specific about where you are getting stuck and you will get more people answering.

Comment: Thanks Borrrden, appreciate what you're saying.  I'll try and elaborate.

Comment: @borrrden Question was removed.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an older post but what type of authentication were you trying to implement? A custom system where users enter a service specific email/password? Facebook auth? Twitter Auth? Google account auth? MSFT account auth?

If you're looking for any of the latter four, you may want to check out WA Mobile Services and these two tutorials:

-Getting started with authentication: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-ios/

-Authorizing users with server-side scripts: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/authorize-users-in-scripts-ios/

Essentially, once you obtain the Client ID and Client Secret from the relevant service, you're then your to write a method that checks to see if a user is already logged in. If not, you'll then display the relevant login option (the first tutorial shows a Facebook auth walk through).

If you were looking for a custom authentication system that allows users to create a service/app specific account, then you might find this post helpful: http://thejoyofcode.com/Exploring_custom_identity_in_Mobile_Services_Day_12_.aspx

Hope this helps,

Miranda